# Jquery push value in array if page exists

Tags: jquery, arrays

I'm trying to make a JSON call that returns some data. Inside my each function I'm trying to check if the returned value (page url)  exists. When it does I want it to push in array which I want to use later in my script. If it does not exist I want to push a different value.
Whatever I try I just can't get it to work. That means my script returns the wrong url or it doesn't pushes the new created url to my array. or at least it's not available in my array.

To clarify:

```
function brandUrlExists(url, callback){
   $.ajax({
       url: url,
       type: 'HEAD',
       success: function(){
        callback(true);
       }
   });
}
function menuBrands(curr, urljson){
  var brandsArr = []
  var br_list = curr.parent().find('.mega-menu .br_list .title')

  $.getJSON(urljson', function(data){

    var maincat = curr.data('maincat')
    $.each(data.brands, function(index, brand){

     var brandUrl = brand.title.replace(' ', '-').toLowerCase()
     
     // I want to test if this "testUrl" works/responds
     var testUrl = brand.title.replace(' ', '-').toLowerCase() + '/' + maincat      
     var newUrl = ''
     
     //if testUrl exists then create var "newUrl" and set "testUrl" otherwise the "brandUrl"
     brandUrlExists(testUrl, result => {
      newUrl = result ? testUrl : brandUrl
     })
     brandsArr.push(newUrl)
    });

    // problem I have here is that either the array has only the last "newUrl" of the list in the array or the array has only the 'brandUrl' as newUrl. 
    br_list.after(brandsArr.sort())
  });
```

I just can't see what I'm doing wrong. Perhaps I'm looking at it for way to long now :(
Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: pay attention: getJSON is an asynchronous call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running many ajax requests. Each request is asynchronous. You seem to know that, since you are passing a callback correctly. Now you have to place all the logic to perform on the ajax responses in that callback.

A layer above, on each `brandUrlExists` call, you should pass the `brand` to make sure the `brandUrl` and the `testUrl` are specific to this function call. Remember you are in a loop.

Additionnally, if the url does not exist, you were not running the callback...

I changed some `var` to `let` to make sure the variable is specific to the scope of its function.

So... I haven't tested anything. Try it:

```
function brandUrlExists(brand, callback){

  // brandUrl and testUrl are specific to this brand check
  let brandUrl = brand.title.replace(' ', '-').toLowerCase()
  let testUrl = brand.title.replace(' ', '-').toLowerCase() + '/' + maincat

  $.ajax({
    url: testUrl,
    type: 'HEAD',
    success: function(){
      callback(true);
    },
    error: function(){ // If the page does not exist
      callback(false);
    }
  });
}

function menuBrands(curr, urljson){
var brandsArr = []
var br_list = curr.parent().find('.mega-menu .br_list .title')

$.getJSON(urljson, function(data){

  var maincat = curr.data('maincat')

  // How many brands to test?
  var brandCount = data.brands.length

  $.each(data.brands, function(index, brand){

    // Squarely pass "brand" to the function
    brandUrlExists(brand, result => {

      let newUrl = result ? testUrl : brandUrl
      brandsArr.push(newUrl)  // Push to array from inside the callback

      // If ALL the ajax requests are done
      if(brandsArr.length === brandCount){
        br_list.after(brandsArr.sort())
      }
    })

  });

});
```